# Cannot run gcc with the -fopenmp flag on macOS

Tags: gcc, openmp

I have gcc 9.3 running on macOS, and I'm running a gcc command with -fopenmp flag, but I get the error: `Unsupported option`error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'```. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP must be enabled when you run configure.  Per default it is enabled, but when your target machine does not come with specific requirements like thread model then it is disabled.

For example, the top-level `config.log` for a gcc build that supports it reads:

```
...
target_configdirs=' libgcc libbacktrace libgomp libatomic libitm libstdc++-v3 libsanitizer libvtv libmpx libssp libquadmath libgfortran libobjc'
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_noncanonical='x86_64-linux-gnu'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_subdir='x86_64-linux-gnu'
...
```

Notice the `libgomp` in `target_configdirs`.  Use the `config.log` as a starting point to find out why your target does not support it.

Comment: Beware too, that on MacOS gcc is often an alias for clang, so run gcc --version to see if that is so. (This from my mac...) $ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$